# Intel TBB v4.3 ignores task_scheduler_init parameter, always runs total threads equal to number of cores

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, intel, tbb

I need to use task_scheduler_init to limit the number of threads to a number under of cores, however TBB ignores the number & always uses the number of cores (8 in this case).

This doesn't look like normal behavior to me. Please note that it is not a possibility for me to use a different version of TBB.

Snippet:

```
task_scheduler_init scheduler(nb_thread);

tbb::parallel_for(
  tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, size),
  [&](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& subrange) {
      int tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
      dragon_draw_raw(
                subrange.begin(),
                subrange.end(),
                dragon,
                dragon_width,
                dragon_height,
                limits,
                id
              );
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

If the `task_scheduler_init` instance was not the first call to TBB on this thread, it explains why you see such a behavior. [Almost] any call to TBB initiates auto-initialization and the number of worker threads is fixed at this time, any further call to `task_scheduler_init` means basically nothing except additional reference to the internal task scheduler object.

If you are in control of the entire application and can make the call to `task_scheduler_init` object constructor the first call to TBB, it will fix your problem. But if you are writing a component or a library, look at `task_arena` feature, it allows to control concurrency limits regardless of the current settings.